# RC snubber on bridge rectifier (capacitor rating)

Tags: capacitor, bridge-rectifier, certification, full-bridge

I am using a bridge rectifier on the mains and across each diode I have placed a RC snubber for EMI mitigation. (C is rated at 1Kv)

My question is...on the C (from the RC snubber) should I use Y or X rating cap ? (I am planing to pass UL/FCC/CE

Right now I am using regular ceramic cap.

Comment: Is there a defined reason why you would use a snubber - a lot of power supplies don't but maybe you've read an article that states otherwise. In the past I've modelled the effects of adding a snubber and found them to be marginally beneficial at best.

Comment: Diode RC snubbing helps in reducing EMI

Comment: @JohanB. Are you just saying that in a general way, or for your application? Because for EMI you'd have to have conditions that generate it, such as series RL loads, where the current turns square-ish and the switchings *may* cause the diodes to oscillate, or when you have a switched load, usually inductive (buck, boost, etc) ant the current has, again, sharp edges, but these are just guesses. So, what are *your* motives (as opposed to *other's* motives and how they apply in your case)? It would help to state this in your question, maybe add a schematic. I dare say noone here can read minds.

Comment: My question is not regarding EMI. I am taking readings and see it. My question is about the capacitor rating (RC snubber) on the bridge rectifier . Since it sees the AC mains , should I use a X caps (rating) or not. (maybe Y cap..)

Comment: @JohanB. a very useful selection guide, depending on your application   https://www.okayaelec.co.jp/dcms_media/other/eg1704_all.pdf

Comment: @JohanB. `I have placed a RC snubber for EMI mitigation`, your words. If that's not the case, then why bother saying? Or doing it, for that matter, since it seems uselss. But, your problem.

Comment: Concerned citizen , yes those are my wordsto form a clear picture but my question is not about EMI. You seem to think its useless, but oscilloscope shows otherwise.  If you can answer about the rating of those caps...great. Concentrating on EMI and usefulness of RC snubber is not helpful .

Comment: If you have a X rated capacitor on both sides of the bridge rectifier then adding more across the diodes is redundant and serves no purpose. NOBODY in the industry does that. UL would mandate it if it actually did something important. I have heard of snubbers across SCRs, but that is all. UL does not define any snubbers for bridge rectifiers. It's your money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, Y capacitors are intended for filtering common mode between line and ground/PE.  X capacitors are intended for filtering across the line: L1-L2 or L-N.  This is described in IEC60384-14 which is harmonised with UL 60384 and EN 60384.

You clearly do not have a Y capacitor application if you're not connecting to chassis/ground/PE.

The peak pulse voltage you would expect to encounter dictates whether you would use an X1 or X2.  For up to 2500V, you can use X2; above that and I believe specified up to 4kV you would need X1.

You mentioned that you plan to obtain UL and CE-Mark for the end product.  I suggest you work with your lab or certifying agent on this detail since it doesn't sound like you are using the capacitor in its intended application (line to line).